# changing dimensionality of allocated memory in c

Tags: c, memory, malloc, avr

Consider an array of framebuffers defined as follows:

`static uint8_t framebuffer[num_buffers][1024];`

The array was defined to have a single dimension per display buffer because the underlying hardware peripheral requires it in my embedded application. However, in other areas of the code, it would be highly advantageous to address the same framebuffers by additional dimensions, e.g.:

`framebuffer[buf][page][col];`

How do I accomplish this? Using real numbers, I would like the range of page to be 0 to 7 and col to be 0 to 127. Note: Each page is 128 bytes. For example, this statement would evaluate to true because they would be referencing the same byte:

`framebuffer[0][130] == framebuffer[0][1][2]`

because 130 / 128 = 1 (page) and 130 % 128 = 2 (column). I'm assuming I need to use malloc, but I've been unsuccessful at producing the correct behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "dimensionality" is not a property of the allocated memory, but the data type.  You can access the same memory through a pointer of a different type with different dimensions provided you take care to ensure that the overall size and alignment are compatible.  So for your example, you could do:

```
static uint8_t framebuffer[numbuffers][1024];

uint8_t (*redimensioned)[8][128] = (uint8_t (*)[8][128])framebuffer;
```

..and then, for example, zero the 4th column of the 3rd page of the 2nd buffer with:

```
redimensioned[1][2][3] = 0;
```

---

To elaborate a bit, the original declaration `uint8_t framebuffer[numbuffers][1024];` declares an array of arrays (`numbuffers` arrays of `1024` `uint8_t`'s).  It would decay to a pointer to arrays of `1024` `uint8_t`'s (or `uint8_t (*)[1024]`, which can also be accessed as an `N x 1024` 2-dimensional array.

We can also access that original array's contents through a pointer to arrays of `8` arrays of `128` `uint8_t`'s, which is what `uint8_t (*redimensioned)[8][128];` gives us, and which we can access as an `N x 8 x 128` 3-dimensional array (after pointing it at the original array's contents).

To keep the compiler happy, when we point `redimensioned` at `framebuffer`'s contents we have to cast it, since the types of the pointer `framebuffer` decays to is different from the type of the pointer we declared... which is where the `(uint8_t (*)[8][128])` comes from in the assignment (it's a cast to "pointer to arrays of 8 arrays of 128 uint8_t's").

Comment: All of the comments and answers have been helpful, but this is exactly what I was envisioning. I think I used to know this better than I currently do as I'm pretty rusty with C. The 'conversion' you demonstrated helps a lot. Thanks.

Comment: The jury is still out on whether accessing the memory via this cast is actually legal, but it is likely to work on any real-world implementations

Answer (score 1):

Instead of accessing the array through a different type of array, I would strongly suggest creating a function to return the right element of the array.

```
uint8_t getFrameBufferItem(uint8_t framebuffer[][1024],
                           int i,
                           int j,
                           int k)
{
   return framebuffer[i][j*128+k];
}
```

Create a similar function to set the value of an item.

```
void setFrameBufferItem(uint8_t framebuffer[][1024],
                        int i,
                        int j,
                        int k,
                        uint8_t val)
{
   framebuffer[i][j*128+k] = val;
}
```

Comment: I realize now that I didn't mention the framebuffers need to be written to, not just read from. This would work to read a specific byte, but I also need to update them as well.

Comment: @R Sahu thanks for the update. I don't remember exactly how that works, but I'm guessing `framebuffer[][1024]` is actually a reference. Wouldn't the overhead of calling a function make this slower than esm's first answer?

Comment: @Anthony, It will be a bit slower than casting the array. I don't know how much.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options.  The first is to create a variable that is a double array of `uint8_t` pointers and do the following:

```
static uint8_t original_framebuffer[num_buffers][1024];
static uint8_t *new_framebuffer[num_buffers][8];
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  new_framebuffer[0][i] = &original_framebuffer[0][i * 128];
}
```

This way `original_framebuffer[0][130]` refers to the same memory location as `new_framebuffer[0][1][2]`

Another option  I would suggest is not exactly what you want but you could just wrap the indices in macro:

```
#define XY_ACCESS(_x, _y) ((_x) * 128 + (_y))
```

Then you would have the following:

```
framebuffer[0][130] == framebuffer[0][XY_ACCESS(1, 2)]
```

You could of course also use a function instead of a macro.

Comment: Clever. The macro would work fine, but the first method would be faster, right? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Anthony I would guess the first method should be faster as the multiplications are done up front, but the first method uses more memory accesses and therefore could suffer more cache misses.  You would really just have to benchmark it